# RegExp to get unit from matrix strings

Tags: javascript, css, regex, units-of-measurement

Say we've some strings like these and need the unit from them:

```
'rotate(90deg)' // 'deg'`
'rect(0 0 5px 5px)' // 'px'
'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' // ''
```

How can i accomplish that?

Comment: For example? `rotate(90deg)` --> `90deg`, `rect(5px 0px 0px 5px)` --> `5px 0px 0px 5px`, `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` --> `0, 0, 0, 0.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should works :

```
/[0-9]+([^ ,\)`]*)/
```

Example :

```
/[0-9]+([^ ,\)`]*)/.exec('rect(5px 0px 0px 5px)')[1]; // 'px'
```

Comment: Can you extend your RegExp to test for the *separator* (comma in `rgb`) too?

Comment: The RegExp already test the comma separator. Where's is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, i meant that it extract the seperator if it is given.

Comment: `/[0-9]+([^ ,\)`]*)/.exec('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')[1]` returns ''. I don't understand. Do you want to get the comma separator in the result ?

Comment: Yeah, correct! Something like this: `/[0-9]+([^ ,\)]*)/.exec('rect(5px 0px 0px 5px)')[2] // ''` and `/[0-9]+([^ ,\)]*)/.exec('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')[2] // ','`

Comment: Here : `/[0-9]+([^ ,\)]*)(,*)/.exec('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)')[2]`

Comment: Mhh, there's a problem with your RegExp... If the unit isn't in the first item it will return `''`. A bit further: `rect(0 0 5px 5px)` returns `''` instead of `'px'`... Any ideas?